# Read a xib and spit the equivalent loadView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xib, loadview

Is there any tool that will read a xib file and spit the corresponding loadView method?

I want to create the views with a xib, but then convert it to Objective C code and use that from then on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called nib2objc out there which you can find on github:
https://github.com/akosma/nib2objc